# Where to really learn the "theory" behind Loop flow, and sculpting

Tags: sculpting, topology

Pardon the title, I am aware that topology is generally a lesser concern with sculpting, but I've been wonder if there was a book or lecture - perhaps on youtube or elsewhere - that could explain both why an artist would aim for a particular loop flow and what general method he or she would apply to sculpting?

Comment: This is a good tutorial by cgcookie https://youtu.be/llOqbJKpK1Y. There might me more on their website bit I haven't checked them.

Answer (score 0):

This site isn't particularly well suited for these broad answers, but here you go anyway :D

[topologyguides.com](https://topologyguides.com) is a great resource for learning about proper topology. For sculpting resources, check out YanSculpts and Zacharias Rienheart on youtube.

Comment: Thank you, I do appreciate the answer especially given your observation on the choice of forum.